# AJAX call error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I have a page that, upon loading, fills 3 drop down menus for uses to select from.  On my localhost, this works fine, but on my live server I get the error in Developer Tools "POST (my site's name) 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8630.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(function() {
    //after load, populate lists
    Update_List_ProcedureAreas_Schedule();
    Update_List_Patients_Cancel();
    Update_List_Cancel_Reasons();
});
```

Here's one of the functions, but the other two are nearly identical, but all 3 fail.  I send to a generic functions php file the function that I want to run, and if there are any parameters with the function as well.  Maybe be a bit weird, but it helps me organize my code:

```
function Update_List_Patients_Cancel() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/functions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {Function_ID: 'pull_patient_list_cancel'},
        success: function(data){
            var dropDown = document.getElementById("selectedpatient_cancel");
            dropDown.options.length=0;
            dropDown[dropDown.length] = new Option('', '')
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dropDown[dropDown.length] = new Option(data[i].Patient_Name, data[i].Patient_UID)
            }
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the PHP in 'php/functions.php' which takes the Function_ID and then uses a switch to verify the input and then call the function with any appropriate variables:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //Make sure a funciton was sent
    if(isset($_POST['Function_ID']) == true) {$tempFunction = $_POST['Function_ID'];}
    else {echo "No fuction selected";}

    //switch to functions
    switch($tempFunction) {
        case 'pull_patient_list_cancel':
            pull_patient_list_cancel();
            break;
    }


//Pull patient list for cancel drop down
function pull_patient_list_cancel() {
    require $_SESSION['db_connect'];  //code to connect to the database, which is successful, btw

    $returnArray = array();

    $sql = "
        SELECT Patient_UID, Patient_Name
        FROM tbl_patients
        WHERE Active = 1
        ";

    if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
        $conn->close();
        foreach($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row) {
            $returnArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($returnArray);
    } else {
        $conn->close();
        echo "Failed - pull patient lists cancel";
    }
}
```

It looks like for some reason, I'm not able to execute in the foreach loop.  I've put in bogus echos to see where the function stops running, and it won't output any echo within the for each loop or after it, but it will up until that loop starts.  I've check the response log in Development Tools and see the bogus echos coming through until the foreach loop, and then nothing.

Any ideas?

------------Solution-----------------

The problem was that I had mysqlnd installed on my localhost xampp setup, but it did not install on my digitalocean lampp server that I set up today.  So that made the fetch_all(MYSQLI) not work. However, I could stick with the mysql installation and use fetch_assoc() and it worked fine.

But, I ended up installing mysqlnd on my digitalocean droplet by using:

apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

and then restarting the server with

service apache2 restart

and now all of my fetch_all(MYSQLI) functions work. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Is your database properly set up? Can you access it and retrieve data without using the loop?

Comment: yes, I do a login in procedure that checks username/password and that works fine, but every other function past that doesn't for some reason it seems... I must have something off because that's too much of a coincidence

Comment: my check log in doesn't do a foreach loop, so that could be why it isn't failing at that stage... weird, something must be wrong in the foreach is what I'm wanting to guess

Comment: You're certain the DB connection information is properly configured for your live environment?

Comment: @ventaur
when i use this code, I'm able to get a correct response and logs my user in:
`code
<?php
 function CheckLogin($userName, $userPW) {
  require 'config/connectraw.php';
  
  $sql = "SELECT userUID, userPW FROM tbl_users WHERE userUID='" . $userName . "' AND userPW='" . $userPW . "'";
  if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
   if($result->num_rows) {
    $conn->close();
    return $result->num_rows;
   }
  } else {
   $conn->close();
   die($con->error);
  }
 }
?>
`

Comment: What's your PHP version? Did you check if mysqli extension installed?

Comment: it looks like changing from
`code foreach($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row) {`
   TO   `code foreach($result->fetch_assoc() as $row) {` will now build the array, so that's a step, but I think it's messing up my json_encode now =(

Comment: I think fetch_assoc returns a single row vs fetch_all

Comment: I'd like to know how to make my fetch_all work because it's riddled in my application, but switching from a foreach loop to a while loop does the trick!  So it solves the problem, but I don't know why my foreach wouldn't work unless it is a version issue.  Here's the code that works now:  
`code   $result = $conn->query($sql);
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $returnArray[] = $row;
  }
  
  echo json_encode($returnArray);`

Comment: @ed-ta on my localhost, I have "mysqlnd" section in phpinfo where I do not have it on my liver server, so I imagine that is the issue that is causing it to not work, so now I need to figure out how to install "mysqlnd" which I'm a novice still, but I'm sure I can google it unless someone can point me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot close the connection before you fetch the results for the foreach. Move the connection close after the loop.

Better still, remove both connection close statements, and put a single one after the else block.

```
if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    foreach($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $returnArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($returnArray);
} else {
    echo "Failed - pull patient lists cancel";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: I moved it out like you have it here, but still the same issue =(

Comment: I suggest displaying errors on this page and using an app like Postman to test calling it. See if you can see the errors in the raw response returned then. http://www.phpreferencebook.com/tips/display-all-php-errors-and-warnings/

Comment: just got this error from turning on errors:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error on your PHP function page....

You cannot use `isset` like this

change your code from

```
    if(isset($_POST['Function_ID']) == true) //which is wrong
```

To

```
     if(isset($_POST['Function_ID']) && $_POST['Function_ID'])==true) 
   // this is the right way
```

Connection should be closed after all the program has executed and

```
   else{} 
   $conn->close();
```

Comment: when I change my if statement to have the && it doesn't go into the function at all anymore.  I put in "echo 'howdy'; right before the for each, and that will display as a response with my initial if statement, but with yours, I don't get that nor my error if the statement is false.  I did move conn close out of the if statement.

Comment: just added it at the bottom of the question

Comment: There is nothing wrong with checking if isset($_POST['Function_ID']) == true because isset returns a boolean value. But Function_ID is not boolean, it is a string so you can't check if $_POST['Function_ID'] is true. Don't do isset don't do switch, just check if($_POST['Function_ID'] == 'pull_patient_list_cancel'). Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  I just add a line at the top of the functions.php file that sets it to equal that to see what response I get from typing the address straight into the browser, and it passes.  It looks like it's not liking the fetch method of mysqli because I get the "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()" response

Comment: Well, it's a minor technicality it doesn't affect your database query. Check PHP version and if mysqli installed.

Comment: @ed-ta this is in php info:  PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7  I just installed my droplet on digital ocean today, so I would think it would be the very latest... but that's probably not good to assume =(